# Vuex reactivity - updating array value in the store doesn't update the computed value in a component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I've the followoing `mutation` setup:

```
state.user.companies[data.index] = data.company;
```

That's correctly updating the value in Vuex as far as I can see in the debugger, but the computed value in the different components don't seem to get the value updated. i.e.

```
company(){
    return this.$store.state.user.companies[this.$store.state.company_index];
},
```

However, if I execute the following mutation, it does work (but it's not what I need in this specific case):

```
state.company_index = data.new_index;
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing to make it work in the first mutation too?

Comment: It’s covered in the documentation that certain changes to arrays cannot be watched/tracked by VueJS (and by extension, VueX): https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays. You’ve just did one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue cannot detect when you directly set a non-root state property with the index. For keeping reactivity use set() method.

```
Vue.set(state.user.companies, data.index, data.company)
```

Comment: Ha! thanks, I was using $set instead and it wasn't working for me - this works, cheers!